# ¿Cómo hacer para que en la función random.randrange el resultado no se repita?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que en un rango de multiplicaciones no se repitan?

```
import random

for i in range(15):
    x = random.randrange(2,9)
    y = random.randrange(2,9)
    z = x * y
    print(x, "*", y, "=", z)
```

Es decir,

```
5 * 7 = 35
6 * 3 = 18
4 * 5 = 20
2 * 6 = 12
8 * 7 = 56
8 * 6 = 48
7 * 6 = 42
3 * 3 = 9
4 * 8 = 32
4 * 3 = 12
2 * 4 = 8
7 * 6 = 42
5 * 7 = 35
6 * 3 = 18
6 * 2 = 12
```

que no se repita así(5*7 ; 5*7), ni así(2*6 ; 6*2)

Comment: No es muy buena descripción del problema... no quieres que se repita el resultado (qué hay con 6*2 yu 3*4), o que no se repitan el mismo par en distinto orden? Por otro lado, si generas los numeros al azar, puede pasar cualquier cosa, puede pasar incluso que todos los valores de x y de y sean iguales. Explicate mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que orientar el problema mejor. Si no quieres repetir pares de números, lo que puedes intentar primero es a generar todos los pares posibles y, entre todos ellos, elegir al azar los que quieras.

Por ejemplo:

```
import random

productos = [(x,y) for x in range(2,10) for y in range(x,10)]

for (x,y) in random.sample(productos,15):
    print("{} * {} = {}".format(x, y, x*y))
```

Comment: Esta respuesta usa `random.sample` que es la opción correcta porque garantiza que los valores no se repiten. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Answer (score 0):

Yo no se Phyton pero te dejo un pseudocode espero te ayude

```
arr[][] no se como sera en Phyton pero creas un 
        array asignas el tamaño si lo nesecita ect.  

int count = 0;
short xC  = 0;
short yC  = 1;

for i in range(15):

do
    x = random.randrange(2,9)
    y = random.randrange(2,9)
    z = x * y

while (llamar a una funcion que mire dentro del array si existen, 
       si no devuelva false, -> compro(x, y))

añade los datos que son los que comprobara despues con la llamada
a la funcion en while

añades los datos que antes no estaban

arr[xC][count] = x
arr[yC][count] = y

count ++

print(x, "*", y, "=", z)

bool compro(compX, compY){

    bool existe = false

    for (int a = 0; a < arr.leng; a++){

        if(arr[xC][a] == compX){
            if(arr[yC][a] == compY){
                existe = true
                usar break o a = arr.leng +10 el caso es salir del for 
            }
        }

        if(arr[xC][a] == compY){ aqui si podria usa el leng
                                 en el caso de que uses arr.leng +10
                                 para que no compruebe este if pero es 
                                 solo un detalle
            if(arr[yC][a] == compX){
                existe = true
                usar break o a = arr.leng +10 el caso es salir del for
            }
        }
    }

    return existe
}
```

Los if se podrian comprimir pero creo que de esta manera se entiende bien. Tambien ten presente cuando implementes la funcion que llames desde el while porque si siempre devuelve true se te quedara dando vueltas

Comment: Por eso nadie quiere usar C o Javascript sino Python, porque es mucho más fácil — y más corto! :-)